# Angular 2 LocalStorage key

Tags: javascript, html, angular, local-storage

I'm working with LocalStorage. In constructor I had done it:

`this.currentData = (localStorage.getItem('currentData')!==null) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentData')) : [  ];`

But doing it I'll store the data in array and I think it isn't good.

So, I did it:

```
constructor(){
if(this.currentData !== null  && this.currentData !== undefined) {
    for (var i = this.currentData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.currentData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentData-' + i));
        console.log('currentData if:' + this.currentData)
    }
} else {
    console.log('currentData else:' + this.currentData)
}
}
```

But I got an error, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

To save data I do it:

```
saveLocalStorage(todo){
    this.objects.push(todo);
    for (var i = this.objects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        localStorage.setItem('currentData-' + i, JSON.stringify(this.objects[i]));
    }
}
```

How could I get the multiples datas from localStorage?
Does anyone know how I fix this problem?

Comment: What does this.currentData contain if you just console.log it?

Comment: And you should implement the for-loop like this instead for easier understanding: for (var i = 0; i > this.objects.length; i--)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the localstorage injected into constructor

Probably you might have forgot `this` key word as below

```
this.currentData = (this.localStorage.getItem('currentData')!==null) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentData')) : [  ];
```

Alternatively, you can use as,

```
user:any[]={name:'abc',id:1};
  valuFromLocalStorage:any{};
  constructor(private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    this.localStorageService.add('a',this.user);
    console.log(this.localStorageService.get('a')); 
    this.valuFromLocalStorage= this.localStorageService.get('a')
  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/BOIyDOKgWey6UbNZrnAl?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm using `localstorage` into constructor. I'll update the code

Comment: Doing it by your answer, I'll have mock the data, and I can't do it. When I insert a new data in localstorage, this new data need to have a unique localstorage key

Answer (score 0):

I made a service do handle the localStorage. Maybe this can help you:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NpStorageService {

  constructor(){
    this.checkIflocalStorageIsAvailable();
  }

  private checkIflocalStorageIsAvailable = () => {
    let type = '';
    try {
      let testKey = '__np_storage_test__' + Date.now();
      type = 'localStorage';
      localStorage.setItem(testKey, 'work');
      localStorage.removeItem(testKey);
      type = 'sessionStorage';
      sessionStorage.setItem(testKey, 'work');
      sessionStorage.removeItem(testKey);
      return true;
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.error('NpStorageService => Cannot find ' + type + ' on this browser.');
      return false;
    }
  }

  get = (key?: string) => {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  }

  set = (key: string, value: any): boolean => {
    try {
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
      return true;
    }
    catch(e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  remove = (key: string) => {
    return localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use to $localStorage service

https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

It easily allows you to interact with the localStorage object and calls digests when data changes.

You can easily add/remove variables like so

```
$localStorage.myObject = {array: [1,2,3,4]};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't using AngularJS, I'm using Angular 2.